# Creating custom tags to find out the people user is following

Tags: django, twitter-follow, django-custom-tags

I want to find out the people I am following on my django simple twitter application. How to make a custom tag for that. I have a custom tag that suggests the user persons to follow:

```
@register.simple_tag
def people_you_may_know(user_id):
    return UserProfile.objects.exclude(
        followers__follower__user_id=user_id
    ).exclude(user_id=user_id)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your model?

Comment: What does work? What does not work?

Comment: @RajeshYogeshwar

https://codeshare.io/dbxat

Comment: You have made use of model functions, why do you need custom template tag for same?

Comment: I have followed a tutorial from django-tips.com exactly, they did it that way. Anyway, Thanks a lot for helping.